# TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, undefined, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot. I would appreciate it, if someone could help me to solve this. I have been searching the whole internet, but I just can't solve it. As far as I investigated, they told me, that I have to define my embed or something like that. I tried to define it, but it still won't work. I get this error:

```
m.embeds[0].description === '**Cooldown**' && m.author.id === '555955826880413696'
            ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

My code:

```
let setHunt = new Set();

client.on('message', rmsg => {
        var sw = rmsg.content.toLowerCase();
        if (sw.startsWith('rpg hunt')) {
            if (setHunt.has(rmsg.author.id)) {
                return;
            }
        const rfilter = m => {
            console.log(rmsg.content);
            m.embeds[0].description === '**Cooldown**' && m.author.id === '555955826880413696'
        };
        const collector = rmsg.channel.createMessageCollector(rfilter, {
            time: 2000,
            max: 1
        });
        collector.on('end', m => {
            if (m.size === 0) {
                let filter = m => {
                    return m.id == '733786365342253087' || m.id == '733786293435105422' || m.id == '733786784336445461' || m.id == '733786616769937439';
                }
                let time;
                let role = rmsg.guild.member(rmsg.author).roles.cache.find(filter);
                if (typeof role == 'undefined') {
                    return
                }
                switch (role.id) {
                    case '733786365342253087': time = 60000; break;
                    case '733786293435105422': time = 54000; break;
                    case '733786784336445461': time = 48000; break;
                    case '733786616769937439': time = 39000; break;
                }
                setHunt.add(rmsg.author.id);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setHunt.delete(rmsg.author.id);
                    rmsg.channel.send(`Your **Hunt** is ready! <@${rmsg.author.id}>`);
                }, time)
            }
        })
    };
});
```

Comment: It's telling you that `embed[0]` is undefined, which means that you haven't assigned anything to the embeds array of the message yet. Also, can you provide where m is defined?

Comment: i think i haven't defined it, how can i do it?